# Horror movie where three cave explorers get picked off by a man or creature who looks like he is burned and escapes into a city

Tags: story-identification, movie, horror

The movie seemed to be set in the late '60s. Colour film. I remember the cave explorers open up a part of a cave that was sealed and the person (or creature?) trapped in there kills them, then escapes into the city and starts stalking people.

Comment: Hi, welcome to the site. In roughly which year did you watch this, and did you watch it on TV or online? If on TV, then in which country and language?

Comment: Similar to this for the stalking...but he's just a caveman https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eegah

Comment: A bit like "The Tomb" (1986), [youtube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GHLrMIPrR1M)

Comment: Might the film be "The Keep" from the early 1980s? The film takes place in a castle rather than a cavern, but involves the release of a trapped monster.https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=video&cd=&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=2ahUKEwiegPS-t7r7AhV6j4kEHTxsBJIQtwJ6BAgJEAI&url=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.youtube.com%2Fwatch%3Fv%3DyYs5hGJFY0k&usg=AOvVaw3sOH-Np8a84_iWINoZG5BG

Comment: yes much like the keep which definitely  has this plot with a ww2 subplot.

Comment: These all sound awesome, by the way.

Comment: Good day. I watched it on television when I was in kindergarden so that would have been in about 1970 or 71. I seem to remember it was in colour. It was in Canada and in english.

Comment: Hi!  It looks like you've lost track of the account you used to post this question.  You should read the help on [merging accounts](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/help/merging-accounts) so you can regain control of your question and edit it.

Answer (score 4):

Some of these aspects match *[Trog](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0066492/?ref_=nv_sr_srsg_0)*, a film from 1970 (fitting with the timeframe of the question), notable for being the last film role of Joan Crawford.

The film indeed begins with three cave explorers. They find an entrance to a previously unknown cave system, and while they are exploring it they are attacked by creature that seems to be half-man half beast. One of the explorers is killed, one is so traumatised that he can barely speak afterwards, but the third member of the party never actually encounters the beast.

The two remaining members of the party return to the surface and alert Dr Brockton, a local anthropologist (played by Crawford) who runs a nearby research institute. She captures the creature and names him Trog (short for "troglodyte"), and declares him to be the "missing link" between apes and humans. Towards the end of the film Trog escapes, but rather than a city he terrorises the local village, killing a greengrocer, a butcher and a passing motorist, and then kidnapping a young girl. Brockton manages to rescue the girl, and Trog is hunted down and killed by the army.

The make-up was quite primitive, but I would not really describe Trog as looking "burned". The actor played the role with a prosthetic ape muzzle and a chest wig, and little else.

[image: Trog emerges from his cave, while being filmed by local news]

[image: Dr Brockton and Trog]

Comment: Thanks for the answers so far but Trog is not it. Seems to me the show was more 60 ish. The creature, burnt man escapes into the city and stalks women.

Comment: @ToddGray Hi. You're now using a different account than the one you used to post this question. If you can no longer access your previous account, that means you've lost the ability to edit this question, leave comments within this thread, or mark a correct answer as [accepted](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer). You can regain the ability to do all these things by clicking on [this link](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/help/merging-accounts) and merging your new account with the previous one.